# I want to make a dropdown menu

Tags: java, awt

help me with  void paint i have imported it and i have imported the graphics.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Add `Panel` or `JPanel` with overriden `paint(Graphics g)` method to your layout. (You can read this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/painting/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TextToGraphicConverter {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = new TextToGraphicConverter().convertTextToGraphic("my text", new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        //then do what you want with the image
    }

    public BufferedImage convertTextToGraphic(String text, Font font) {

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();

        g2d.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int height = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.dispose();

        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3725193, Im glad :). Please set the answer as correct if you find it appropriate enough to your need.